# How to reuse an element inside of a function in protractor page object model?

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor

I am using protractor with Jasmine in windows 10 OS. This is my page for stack over flow login .May I know how to access txt_username inside of  clearme: function().

pgstackover.js

```
//pgstackover.js
'use strict';   
module.exports = {  

          txt_username: element(by.id('email')),
          txt_password: element(by.id('password')),
          btn_submit: element(by.id('submit-button')),

          clearme: function() {                 
              txt_username.isDisplayed();  
              txt_username.clear();
              txt_password.clear()  
          } , 

         go: function() {  
                browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true;
                browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
                browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
                browser.driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/users/login'); //overrides baseURL  
            }
```

This is my spec.js file and it works until clear me function  and fails with error  Failed: txt_username is not defined

```
var toDoPage = require('../../../../pages/pgstackover.js');  

describe('My first non angular class', function() {

     it('should navigate to stack overflow login page', function() {  
            toDoPage.go();  
          }); 

    it ('My function', function() {
       // browser.driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/users/login');
        toDoPage.txt_username.sendKeys('6');
        toDoPage.txt_password.sendKeys('winchester');
        var value=toDoPage.btn_submit.getText();
        expect(value).toEqual("Log in");        

    });

     it('clear me', function() {  
            toDoPage.clearme();  
          });


})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too make long story short your code does not know what is `txt_username` so you need to point it out. You are missing `.this` in your `clearme` function.

I haven't used a **promise manager** for ages (since it is obsolete) so here is a working example using async/await:

```
  async clearme() {
    await this.txt_username.isDisplayed();
    await this.txt_username.clear();
    await this.txt_password.clear();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Yuriy Gerasimovich. It worked like a charm. Have a nice day .